# Oracle SQL constraint to ensure data format

Tags: sql, constraints, oracle12c, sql-like

I'm trying to ensure that the data that goes into a cell/field in a data row follows the format YYYYAB, YYYYAC, YYYYAD.  Meaning that any four number year and then the two characters "AB" or "AC" or "AD" are valid, anything else would be rejected.

Not sure how to compose the constraint with a like condition and the "_" or the "%" wildcards in order to accomplish this when I'm creating the column.

I was hoping to use something with a syntax like:

`constraint cksemester check (SEMESTER in ( _ _ _ _ A B, _ _ _ _ A C, _ _ _ _ A D)),`

or a combination of % and Regex..... is there a way to restrict the format to essentially any four numbers
and then force the suffix to be any of "AB" or "AC" or "AD" ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without regular expressions using the `TRANSLATE` function:

```sql
CONSTRAINT cksemester CHECK (
  TRANSLATE(
    semester,
    '0123456789',
    '0000000000'
  ) IN ('0000AB', '0000AC', '0000AD')
)
```

If you want to use regular expressions (which typically execute slower than simple string functions, such as `TRANSLATE`) then you can use:

```sql
CONSTRAINT cksemester CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(semester, '^\d{4}A[BCD]$') )
```

Comment: When I research translate: 
TRANSLATE ( source_string, from_string, to_string )
So above, semester was my column name, a value in the format of YYYYAA (read as 4 digit year and then two letter abbreviation would come in as data)  is there a place holder for that and can you clarify what the '0123456789' and the subsequent '0000000000' is doing here?  Thank you.

Comment: Translate just replaces characters in the `from_string` with the corresponding characters in the `to_string`; so it will replace all the digits with zeroes and then the `IN` comparison checks that it has 4 zeroes (which is what we replaced the digits with) and then `AB`, `AC` or `AD`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a REGEX to validate your field. A check constraint works like a where condition, so:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
  add constraint cksemester 
  check (REGEXP_LIKE(SEMESTER,'[[:digit:]]{4}(AB|AC|AD)','I'));
```

This regex ensures:

- `[[:digit:]]{4}` : Exact four digits
- (AB|AC|AD) : either `AB` or `AC` or `AD`
- the `'I'` parameter stands for case insensitive

Edit:

As suggested by MT0 in the comments, a better version of the above regex is `^[[:digit:]]{4}(AB|AC|AD)$`

- `^` ensures the string needs to start there, from the 4 digits
- `$` ensures the string finishes there, it need to end after the "or" expression.

This improved regex, prevent "outbounds" of the original one such as `XYZ1234ABCDEF` which would be considered valid and it is not.

Comment: This would match `XYZ1234ABCDEF`. If you want to only match 4-digits and then 2 letters then you need to include anchors for the start of the string `^` and the end of the string `$`.

Comment: so the entire expression would be:
 (REGEXP_LIKE(SEMESTER, '^[[:digit:]]{4}(AB|AC|AD)$', 'I'));   ?

It goes without saying that I'm not very good at regular expressions. 
Thank you.

Comment: @Effectsmeister Yes, that would be correct. I will edit the answer to reflect MT0 suggestion.

Comment: @MT0 you are correct. Thanks for the suggestion, will edit to to add it.